# Not able to access view from onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following scenario in Fragment :

```
     onCreateView(){
       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
       ScrollView sc = (scrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.sc);
       generateUI() 
       return view; }

       public void generateUI() {  
       horizontalllayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());  
       horizontalllayout.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
       Button newbtn = new Button(getActivity());
       newbtn.setId(1);
       horizontalllayout.addView(newbtn);
       newbtn.setOnClickListener( 
      public void onClick(View v) {  
       Intent CaputureIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), s.class); 
       startActivityForResult(CaputureIntent, 664);  
       } });  


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if(resultCode == 1666){  
    populate("hi");  
    }
    } 

      public void populate(String str) { 
        Button b = (Button)getActivity().findViewbyId(1);    //Error     
        b.setText(str); 
      }  
    }
```

I am  not able to receive the context. The text on the button is not changed in populate() method , when I call from onActivityResult(). If I call the same method from outside every thing is working fine. Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: That code won't compile (onCreateView sig is not there, "scrollView" is lower case, and so on). You might want to try again and put in real code and see if you get more/better responses. That said, startActivityForResult takes the "requestCode" param and you're passing 664. Your onActivityResult logic checks against "resultCode" and looks for 1666. I don't see "setResult" so not sure why it should change the button text in onActivityResult?

Comment: use   if(resultCode == 664)   instead of   if(resultCode == 1666)

Answer (score 1):

assuming Button is deined inside your layout file and your code is typed correctly, set b to be accessible through whole your code by defining b in your class:

```
Button b;
```

and then access b inside onCreateView() like this:

```
b = (Button)view .findViewbyId(1);
```

inside onActivityResult just use b however you like it:

```
b.setText(str);
```

Comment: But in my case I got multiple buttons which I add dynamically, so I can't declare a particular button globally as I can't identify which button I clicked .

Comment: you are right.this wont work.Have you tried using handlers?Im not sure if it helps or not.inside onActivityResult you send a msg with msg.what() and inside your activity there is a handleMessage method which listens and changes UI as you like.